# get the value of scala Some(text)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have some fields in my form whose value is optional. Now, if the value are inserted in these fields, then this returns Some(*the_input_value*) And if not inserted then None is returned. I want to get the value null if not inserted and inserted value if inserted. How?Help!
here is my class:

```
case class Registration(
fname:Option[String], 
lname:Option[String],user_email:String,
user_password:String,
gender:Option[String]
)
```

here is my  form mapping:

```
val registrationForm=Form(
mapping(
  "fname"->optional(text), 
  "lname"->optional(text),
  "user_email"->text, 
  "user_password"->text,
  "gender"->optional(text)
  )(Registration.apply)(Registration.unapply)
```

);

here is my form:

```
@(registrationForm:Form[Registration])

@helper.form(routes.Application.registration_process){      
    @helper.inputText(registrationForm("fname"),'_label->"First Name")
@helper.inputText(registrationForm("lname"),'_label->"Last Name")
@helper.inputText(registrationForm("user_email"),'_label->"Email")
@helper.inputPassword(registrationForm("user_password"),'_label->"Password")
@helper.inputPassword(registrationForm("re-password"))
@helper.inputText(registrationForm("gender"),'_label->"Gender")

<input type="submit" value="Register">
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Best and shortest way is to use `orNull`:

```
scala> val op = Option("String")
op: Option[String] = Some(String)

scala> val res = op.orNull
res: String = String
```

But i highly recommend not to use `null`. Better `op.getOrElse("")`

Comment: 1: `op.orNull`. 2: Question is about JSON mapping.

Comment: @senia can't play automatically marshal `None` into Json `null`?

Comment: @AlexIv but when i use println(op) then Some("String") gets printed But i want simple "String" printed how?

Comment: @user2155922 `println(op.orNull)` or `println(op.getOrElse(""))`. Second way is better